# Idle down transformer

Tags: transformer

How much does a 3000 watt down transformer consume when not used?  In NZ and use my usa clothes washer. Should I TURN IT OFF when not used?

Comment: Seems like a 3kW transformer would cost more than a new washer - just an observation ...

Comment: Based on Charles' figures, 60W x 24 hours =~ 1.5 kWh/day. That's about $NZ0.35/day at 25 cents/unit (varies). Or about 1/2 hour of full power use/day. As the washer probably only uses that much power when it is heating water (if you use it in the self heating mode) then that's perhaps equivalent to a dryer run per day. ie turning it off sounds attractive. || For interest: 1 kWh will heat 850 litre.°C of water - so if heating is from 20C to 50C = 30C delta then you get 850/30 = 28 litres heated per kWh.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought the cheapest transformer you could find, the full-load losses might be as much as 240 watts and the no-load losses as much as 60 watts. That estimate is made with a small amount of internet research.

Comment: You'd be proposing 2 to 8 percent.  Reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The power that is wasted is in the iron core of the transformer when there is no load. It does not matter if the transformer is step up or 1:1 or step down. The finite magnetising inductance of the real transformer means that idle current flows. This current is called magnetising current. The real iron has losses so the magnetising current is not lagging the mains voltage by 90 degrees. Real power is lost. A guess without seeing the transformer would be 2% or 60 watts. This will add up when left on 24/7. In fact if you spend 1% of your time washing clothes ie  If you dont have 11 kids or run a commercial laundry then the 3000 watt transformer will cost more power than washing your clothes.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you should turn it off when not used.

Comment: because...? Could you please give the answer some more body. The answer has been flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.

Comment: Obviously (of course) turn it off because it wastes expensive electricity when idling.